# Azure DevOps extension custom hub group and hub under Organization Settings

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to add a custom hub group and hub under Organization Settings.

Currently I am doing this but the menu is under Extensions hub group.

How can I customize that one so that I will have a custom hub group:

```
{
   "contributions": [
    {
        "id": "collection-level-admin-hub",
        "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
        "description": "Description",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-web.collection-admin-hub-group"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "My Menu",
            "order": 100,
            "uri": "dist/index.html"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only for UI design, also for **security** reasons, we will never run code from untrusted extensions (e.g. all **third party** extensions) in the **same frame** as VSO content.

Contributions from these extensions will provide a uri property that our contribution controls will use to draw the extension's content (in an iframe). This means you can not modify or customize any thing that at the same level with like Pipelines, General or security.

So, in this ticket, you can not add the customized name to replace this default display **Extensions**.

---

If you don't want it display under Extension part, but under like General/Pipelines, you can use the below sample:

```
 "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "sample-hub-group",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.tab",
            "description": "Adds a 'Sample UI' hub group",

            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-admin-web.collection-admin-hub-tab-group"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "System Group",
                "order": 100,
                "uri": "my-hub.html"
            }
        }
    ],
```

Collection level:

**General** : ms.vss-admin-web.collection-admin-hub-tab-group

**Pipeline**: ms.vss-build-web.build-release-account-settings-tab-group

**Repos**(Haven't display default in Org setting):ms.vss-code-web.code-account-settings-tab-group

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. replaced the whole contributions with your example above. Doesn't work. I think adding hub groups to Organization Settings menu doesn't work anymore. Please try ti yourself and let me know if it works.

Comment: Any feedback on this? I think that DevOps doesn't allow anymore to create hub groups at the Organization Level. That's why there is that generic hub group called Extensions where all the hubs targeting the Organization will be shown under...but I might be wrong. Can you please show a full example of a vss-extension.json that will create a custom hub group and a hub/link option under that hub group in Organization Settings page level? As I mentioned the example you shown above doesn't work.

Comment: @user2818430 This is what I am confirmed with our corresponding team, to know is it true that the organization setting does not allow the hub group added any more. It was fine but not now.

Comment: @user2818430 What I am confirming is does this as designed after the UI changed. Last year it work fine with the old Ui of VSTS. Forgive me did not try it with latest UI and share it to you. Will update here to give you exactly message soon.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for taking the time and confirming this. I was suspecting it :)

Comment: @user2818430, Still need apologize this again. Hope you could got my words. I have got reply from ourside. Sorry to say that until now, we do not allow this action because of frame security. If has further puzzle, feel to let me know, I would continue to give you assistance.